# how to get mediawiki sections to include a right-clickable link to the section?

Tags: mediawiki

In some places -- [for example, this github README](https://github.com/protesilaos/modus-themes#modus-themes-for-gnu-emacs), you have sections that automatically generate a little link/section icon that the user can right-click on to get a link to that particular section.

In mediawiki syntax, I can do

```
=== My Section ===
```

and it will render with a `[edit]` bit on the right side, where I can click to edit -- but I don't want to edit, I just want to copy a hyperlink.

Is there a way in mediawiki to get such right-clickable hyperlinks for section titles? Anything reasonable will work; if the above rendered as something like so:

```
 My Section [edit]
```

or

```
§ My Section [edit]
```

with the left-side icons working like the Github example above, that would be very usable.

I've done a lot of searching through mediawiki syntax documentation and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a header that refers to itself:

```
=== [[#Foobar|Foobar]] ===

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

> #### [Foobar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77574393#Foobar)
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

You can also put a nicely `&sect;` before the header:

```
=== [[#Foobar|&sect;]] Foobar ===

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

> #### [§](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77574393#Foobar) Foobar
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

A template would look something like this:

```
<!-- Template:Linkable header -->[[#{{{1}}}|&sect;]] {{{1}}}
```

```
=== {{Linkable header|Foobar}} ===
```

Alternatively, you can use JS to dynamically add links wherever you want them to be, but that depends on your skin and such.

Answer (score 0):

On wp.fr, there is a gadget that adds [URL] and [[Link]] next to the [edit] link on the right of the section title, that copies in the clipboard the URL or the wikicode of the link to that section.

Its code is on [MediaWiki:Gadget-AncreTitres.js](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-AncreTitres.js) and it seems designed for both French and English (I think the switch between [[Lien]] and [[Link]] depends of you language setting in your Preferences.

To use it on wp.en, you have to add
`importScript(':fr:MediaWiki:Gadget-AncreTitres.js');`
to your common.js (`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:<user name>/common.js`)

Another way to get the URL to a section is to click on its link in the table of contents of the page, then copy its URL in your browser URL bar.
Either in the URL and wikicode, `#<section name>` is added to the name of the page.